# Retrieve field from LocalDate that has more than one event

Tags: java, android

I am building a Calendar app that add event and then in every specific date you can see the events. My problem is that in every date block I am trying to add inflated block that will show in every date the title of the event and if the user wants to see more details he can with double tap. In every block will be shown only 2 events titles because of space. I am using DatabaseHelper, when a date have 2 events, these two events have in common only the date. So when I try to show these seperate events I can't find a way to retrieve the second event because the code read the first one in the specific date and the second one in this date is ignored.

**Number is the day of each month: Ex: 5 of January
The two blocks down are the titles of the events inside this day, when there only one event in this day, the second block is hidden.**

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried and ideally a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for the interest, but I found a solution my own after struggling.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Yes I just did it.. If you found my question useful please upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve field from LocalDate that has more than one event

I am building a Calendar app that add event and then in every specific date you can see the events. My problem is that in every date block I am trying to add inflated block that will show in every date the title of the event and if the user wants to see more details he can with double tap. In every block will be shown only 2 events titles because of space. I am using DatabaseHelper, when a date have 2 events, these two events have in common only the date. So when I try to show these seperate events I can't find a way to retrieve the second event because the code read the first one in the specific date and the second one in this date is ignored.

**SOLVED**

I solved it using 2 loops to iterate through the ArrayList of object Event, the first loop begin from 0 and the second from arraylist size. I compare where the localdate values are same, and then I insert the correct value to the block.

My code:

```
ArrayList<Event> myEvents = new ArrayList<>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Event eventDB = new Event(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
                    CalendarUtils.stringToLocalDate(cursor.getString(3)), LocalTime.parse(cursor.getString(4)));
            myEvents.add(eventDB);
        }


        cursor.moveToPosition(0);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {



            for (int i = 0; i < myEvents.size(); i++) {
                if (myEvents.get(i).getDate().equals(date) && LocalTime.parse(cursor.getString(4)).equals(myEvents.get(i).getTime())) {

                    holder.eventDayText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.eventDayText.setText(myEvents.get(i).getName());
                    holder.eventDayText.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    holder.eventDayText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);



                    for (int j = myEvents.size()-1; j >= 0; j--) {
                        if (myEvents.get(i).getDate().equals(myEvents.get(j).getDate()) && i < myEvents.size() ) {
                            if (myEvents.get(j).getName().equals(myEvents.get(i).getName())) {
                                holder.eventDayText2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            } else {
                                holder.eventDayText2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.eventDayText2.setText(myEvents.get(j).getName());
                                holder.eventDayText2.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                holder.eventDayText2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);

                            }
                        }

                    }

                }


            }
```